# 'active_id' for project in kanban view?

Tags: button, view, odoo, odoo-9, kanban

I've added a notes section in the project kanban view. The problem is when I click it I get an error `NameError: name 'active_id' is not defined`

I've used this method to create smart buttons in project, contact, and product form views and it works well. When you click the smart button it will redirect to a pre-filtered notes page. I fear that since there's not really an "active" project open, that there will not be an active_id. If that's the case, how can I filter by the one I've clicked on?

Kanban view

```
<record id="view_project_notes_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">triangle.project.note.kanban</field>
  <field name="model">project.project</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_project_kanban"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_project_kanban_boxes']" position="inside">
        <div class="o_project_kanban_box">
            <a name="%(note.action_note_note)d" type="action" context="{'search_default_project': active_id, 'default_project': active_id}">
              <span class="o_value"><field name="note_count"/></span>
              <span class="o_label">Notes</span>
            </a>
        </div>
      </xpath>
    </data>
  </field>
</record>
```

Form view (which works)

```
<record id="view_project_notes_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">triangle.project.note.form</field>
  <field name="model">project.project</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
      <xpath expr="//div[@name='button_box']" position="inside">
        <button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" name="%(note.action_note_note)d"
          icon="fa-sticky-note" context="{'search_default_project': active_id, 'default_project': active_id}">
            <field string="Notes" name="note_count" widget="statinfo"/>
        </button>
      </xpath>
    </data>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I adjusted my method a little bit because the context should actually be on the note.note action and not the project.project view.

New Project Kanban:

```
<record id="view_project_notes_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">triangle.project.note.kanban</field>
  <field name="model">project.project</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_project_kanban"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_project_kanban_boxes']" position="inside">
        <a name="%(triangle.act_project_2_note)d" type="action" class="o_project_kanban_box">
          <span class="o_value"><field name="note_count"/></span>
          <span class="o_label">Notes</span>
        </a>
      </xpath>
    </data>
  </field>
</record>
```

New Note Window Action:

```
<act_window id="act_project_2_note"
 name="Notes"
 res_model="note.note"
 view_mode="kanban,tree,form"
 context="{'search_default_project': [active_id], 'default_project': active_id}"/>
```

This totally solved my problem!

Comment: Good, next time you should Improve your question with your all findings and affecting codes

Answer (score 2):

Please try record.id instead of active_id, ie :-

```
    <record id="view_project_notes_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="name">triangle.project.note.kanban</field>
     <field name="model">project.project</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_project_kanban"/>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <data>
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_project_kanban_boxes']" position="inside">
       <div class="o_project_kanban_box">
        <a name="%(note.action_note_note)d" type="action" context="{'search_default_project': record.id, 'default_project': record.id}">
          <span class="o_value"><field name="note_count"/></span>
          <span class="o_label">Notes</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </xpath>
     </data>
    </field>
   </record>
```

Comment: This is definitely a good idea, however, it still comes back with an error. `NameError: name 'record' is not defined`. Really not sure how to debug this one!

Comment: Just a little more info: The `record.field` method DOES work for me in a res.partner inherited view, but NOT in the project.project inherited view.

Comment: Can you please specify which version are you working on

Comment: In case of v9 if you are , then try to get the value of id with record ie, record.id.value

Comment: Yes, it is v9. As stated above, I get a NameError on 'record'. Even if I tried 'record.id.value' it would still error on 'record'.